# proc sql union with different variables

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I'm trying to concatenate two tables using a `proc sql - union` where certain variables are unique to each table. Is there a way to do this without using a `NULL` placeholder variable? Basically the equivalent of the following data step.

```
data total;
set t1 t2;
run;
```

A simple example of what I'm trying to do is shown below.

```
data animal;
input common $ Animal $ Number;
    datalines;
a Ant 5
b Bird .
c Cat 17
d Dog 9
e Eagle .
f Frog 76
;
run;


data plant;
input Common $ Plant $ Number;
    datalines;
g Grape 69
h Hazelnut 55
i Indigo .
j Jicama 14
k Kale 4
l Lentil 88
;
run;

proc sql;
(select animal.*, '' as plant from animal)
union all corresponding
(select plant.*, '' as animal from plant)
;
quit;
```

I'd like to be able to run the `proc sql` with having to create the `plant` and `animal` variables in the `select` statement.

Comment: Do note you are not using NULLs but zero length strings (non-null values).

Comment: @Parfait These are nulls in SAS insofar as SAS has null.  (They're actually *not* zero length strings, they're one length strings, `''` evaluates to `' '` in SAS.)

Comment: Thanks @Joe for that clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `outer union`, not `union all`.  That does what you expect (keeps all variables in either dataset).  See [Howard Schreier's excellent paper on SQL set theory](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/242-31.pdf) for more information.

```
proc sql;
create table test as
select * from animal
outer union corr
select * from plant
;
quit;
```

Comment: Wow... can't believe I missed that. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Interesting method. Though, AFAIK, the `outer union` is not ANSI SQL but strictly SAS's dialect. So this will not work should you connect to other RDBMS (Oracle, DB2, SQL Server, Postgres, MySQL).

Comment: @Parfait Good point.  If there's a way to do this in ANSI SQL, it might make a good second answer (as that way should probably also work in SAS; mostly SAS's SQL dialect is ANSI-plus).

Comment: The OP's original attempt with `UNION ALL` (no `corresponding` clause) would probably be the only way I can see for portable SQL code.